# Send GID_ZOOM Gesture to the Active Window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, touch, gesture

How can I send a zoom gesture to the current active window?
I tried creating a GESTUREINFO struct but I do not know how to pass the struct properly. So far, here's what I got.

```
GESTUREINFO gi;
POINT pt;
ZeroMemory(&gi, sizeof(GESTUREINFO));
gi.dwID = GID_ZOOM;
GetCursorPos(&pt);
gi.ptsLocation.x = pt.x;
gi.ptsLocation.y = pt.y;
gi.ullArguments = value;
gi.cbSize = sizeof(GESTUREINFO);

::SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GESTURE, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(&gu.ullArguments), reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&gi));
```

Is my way of sending the WPARAM and LPARAM wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot fake input using `SendMessage`. [WM_GESTURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353242.aspx) is no exception. While *wParam* is easy to construct, the system does not offer an API to create a **handle** to a [GESTUREINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353232.aspx), which needs to be passed as *lParam*.

Starting with Windows 8, there is the [Touch Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802898.aspx) API that allows you to generate touch input for arbitrary targets. Note that touch input is inherently more complex than mouse input (because of contact-area size, multi-touch, pressure, and other factors), so be prepared that it's not as simple as simulating mouse input by calling [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).

Comment: So can I create fake touch inputs instead in order to trigger a zoom gesture?

Comment: @Garren: Starting with Windows 8 there is the [Touch Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802898.aspx) API, that allows you to generate touch input for arbitrary targets. Touch input is inherently more complex than mouse input (contact area size, multi-touch, pressure, etc.), so be prepared that it's not as simple as simulation mouse input calling [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).